# how to enable WebSocket with nginx on AWS Elastic Beanstalk server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deploy a nodejs application on the aws beanstalk servers and want to use socket.io feature based on WebSocket protocol. I know there's a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907302/websockets-with-socket-io-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk) to directly connect to nodejs servers instead of using nginx as an proxy server. But if I still want to have the nginx as proxy server because of extra features provide by nginx, such as static files, ...etc.

I find it's already support [WebSocket proxying](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) on nginx 1.3.13 and I found it seems aws elastic-beanstalk still use the 1.2.x nginx.

So I am wondering if there's any way to upgrade nginx version under beanstalk and how to enable WebSocket proxying to nodejs server.

Thanks

Comment: For upgrading nginx version, you can use [Configuration File](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html). After you upgraded the nginx version, you should double check the parameters which were passed from EB.

Comment: Do you have an example of updating nginx?

Comment: Check this out if you are using elastic beanstalk. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584103/socket-io-in-aws-elasticbeanstalk-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use elastic beanstalk with multiple docker containers(allows you custom nginx version) with following

1.Nginx config

```
location /ws/ 
{
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_pass http://unix:/<<socket>>;
}
```

2. Enable TCP mode load balancing in elastic load balancer if you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

You would need additional module enabled, which can be done during nginx compilation. 
To do that you would need to add below line to your configuration script.

```
--add-module=/root/nginx_patched/nginx_tcp_proxy_module
```

It is required if you would like to get sockets enabled, for example for node.js socket.io. Full tutorial can be found [here](http://blog.i-evaluation.com/2012/12/09/installing-nginx-with-websockets-support/). 
Sorry for the link but it is quite broad topic. You might need step by step guide if you starting from the scratch.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Would you address the version consideration in the question (1.3.13 v. 1.2.x) in your solution?