# Socket Io in AWS ElasticBeanStalk Node

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a node js application in Elastic Bean stalk.We are considering using socket io for a feature .

I read in some places that socket io support has to be manually enabled in AWS elasticbeanstalk. Specifically when it uses the default NGINX proxy.

I read By default an elastic beanstalk instance has an nginx proxy in front of it that is not configured to allow webSockets.

Is this correct information? If so , how to enable socket io support in AWS EB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct information. You'll need to do some additional configuration for your Elastic Beanstalk deployment to get WebSockets(Socket.io or otherwise) to work.

Once you create your Elastic Beanstalk Environment, you'll need to configure your load balancer to accept TCP connections, and add a configuration file to your node project's root directory:

**Configure Load Balancer:**

- Head over to your EC2 console and select the Load Balancers tab
- Select the load balancer that belongs to your ELB environment from
  the list
- Select the Listeners tab
- Change the default entries' **Instance Protocol** to TCP

**Add the Configuration File:**

- In the root directory of your node project, create a folder called
  `.ebextensions`

Create a file called `enable-websockets.config` in your new `.ebextensions` folder with the following contents:

```
container_commands:
  enable_websockets:
    command: |
      sed -i '/\s*proxy_set_header\s*Connection/c \
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;\
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";\
              proxy_pass_request_headers on;\
              ' /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
```

This file tells the NGINX reverse proxy how to handle the `HTTP 101` upgrade status code that WebSockets need to communicate with your application server.

Comment: My http url works fine.It uses WS itself.  But when i use the https ,it switches back to Polling .do you know why

Comment: @Jocket The command adds the lines following `sed -i` to the temporary NGINX configuration file  Elastic Beanstalk uses during deployment. There's currently no way to directly access the NGINX configuration files of EB, so it's necessary to modify them during runtime/deployment. As for your https issue, you'll need to configure an SSL certificate for your balancers port 443 TCP listener. I'm sure you can find details on how to do this in the AWS docs. If you've found this helpful please consider upvoting or marking the answer as accepted!

Comment: I have SSL certificate for my load balancer. All my other APi's go through HTTPS.
the websocket is not somehow not working in ssl.

Change the default entries' Instance Protocol to TCP.. How this should be done for https?

Comment: Note that if you're using a zip file upload, ensure you copy the `.ebextensions` folder into the zip.

Comment: Just a heads up note here, enter this page in 2022, and this solution is no longer valid. The config file will end up deployment failure. I followed this one to succeed: https://solitaired.com/websockets-elastic-beanstalk