# socket.io error - web socket connection is closed before the connection is established

Tags: node.js, sockets, chat

I learned a bit from this page - > https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1846

**Do I need SSL for sockets to work?**

[image]

I've been struggling with this error for a long time with no solution so far, can any geniuses out there to solve the puzzle?

**My App Code**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/html'));

http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    new shell.Shell(app, io);
});


app.use(function(request, response, next){
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token");
        request.id = self.id++;
        next();
    }); 

    var self = this;

    app.get("/", function(request, response) {
        response.end("");
    });

    app.get("/entitlement/:uri", function(request, response){
        self.delegate.entitlement(request, response);
    });

    app.get("/speakers", function(request, response) {
        self.delegate.speaker(request, response);
    });

    app.get("/speakers/:id", function(request, response) {
        self.delegate.speaker(request, response);
    });

    app.get("/sponsors", function(request, response){
        self.delegate.sponsor(request, response);
    });

    app.get("/sponsors/:id", function(request, response) {
        self.delegate.sponsor(request, response); 
    });

    app.get("/agendas", function(request, response) {
        self.delegate.agenda(request, response);
    });

    app.get("/agendas/:id", function(request, response) {
        self.delegate.agenda(request, response); 
    });

    app.get("/sessions/:id", function(request, response){
        self.delegate.agenda(request, response);
    });

    app.get("/attendees", function(request, response) {
        //self.delegate.attendee(request, response);    
    });

    ///attendees/:id to get chat history

    io.on("connection", function(socket){

        //self.delegate.connection(io, socket, null);

        socket.on('get-age-in-dog-years', function(data, fn) {
            console.log(data);
            fn(data.age * 7) ;
        });

        socket.on("chat", function(chat){
            //self.delegate.chat(io, socket, chat);
        });

        socket.on("disconnect", function(){
            //self.delegate.disconnect(io, socket)
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: This is error 400 bad request. Seems to be client is expecting a websocket connection and upgrade handshake may not be happening. You can do a tcpdump and see ws handshake

Comment: i commented few lines of code and it worked, those lines include app.use middleware stuff (header related), also deleted node_modules folder and reinstalled with save, (thought it worked on localhost), I'll try to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

You might be attaching socket.io to the wrong item on the server side.  Your http object is unneccessary when using express.  you can attach it directly to the express app? See here:

http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-the-express-framework

```
var io = require('socket.io')(app)
```

That may be giving you an incorrect reference for your app to attach to.

Comment: I believe he's got it correctly configured for express 4.